# How to figure out if I have statistically significant data? Do I need more samples?

Tags: statistical-significance

I'm trying to figure out if the difference between 0uM and 100uM is statistically significant, especially for the two values for 4 nuclei, 47.196 and 4.745. I want to know if more cells need to be looked at in order to have statistically significant difference. There is around a 42% difference between 0 uM and 100 uM in 4 nuclei. There are 642 cells for 0 uM and 569 for 100 uM. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you examined 303 cells and found that, on average, 47.1962617% of the cell was occupied by something of interest, and you examined 27 cells and found that, on average, 4.74516696% of the cell was occupied by something of interest?

Comment: The number of observations in your data is sufficient to find some highly significant differences. See my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to post an answer under the assumption that my comment to the original question is correct.

I will make two assumptions about what you're doing.

1. You're interested in using statistical methods that pretty much every biologist knows.
2. You're interested in means.

Perhaps the first week or so of an intro statistics class will cover something called the two-sample t-test. The setup is that you have a basket of observations in your right hand and a basket of different observations in your left hand. You want to investigate if the mean values of the baskets are different. Rather, you want to know if the *greater populations* from which the observations in the baskets were drawn have different means. That's what it means to do inferential statistics.

The t-test works by comparing how spread out the data are to how far apart the means of the two groups are. The greater the spread of the data, the less plausible it is that the observed difference between sample means represents a difference in population means. However, if the data are not very spread out, then it won't take much of a difference in sample means to convince you that something is going on.

(I thought about posting images, but I think it will be a good exercise for you to try to visualize what's going on.)

The math is worked out on Wikipedia and I'm sure other questions on here. You're probably more interested in the particular method to use. It will depend on some assumptions you're willing to make about your data, but you're likely willing to make those assumptions. In that case, the two-sample t-test is fine.

To find a p-value for that sample with four nuclei, you will either have to know the variances of the samples of 303 and 27, or you will have to have access to the data to go calculate the variances yourself. Most likely you have the data saved in an Excel file or something similar and can use software (such as Excel, R, or Python) to grind through all of the math.

For better or for worse, $p\le 0.05$ is typically taken as being statistically significant. Whatever you decide is the appropriate cutoff value (perhaps going by an advisor's advice or what others in your field do), a p-value falling below that value indicates evidence that the population means are indeed different.

(There are caveats to this answer, but this is how a first statistics class would go.)

Answer (score 1):

**Chi-squared test of homogeneity.** It seems these data should be analyzed using a chi-squared
test of homogeneity. It seems that larger cell counts happen
more often in the first group $0\mu M$ than in the second
group $100\mu M.$ Putting the last two tables together, we have
the following data matrix `DTA`.

Input data for `MAT`

```
a = c(101,79,159,203);  b = c(358, 115, 69, 27)
sum(a); sum(b)   # verify column totals
[1] 542
[1] 569
MAT = cbind(a,b);  MAT
       a   b
[1,] 101 358
[2,]  79 115
[3,] 159  69
[4,] 203  27

lbl="Number of Cells: Nuclii by Groups 0uM (Blue), 100uM (Maroon)"
barplot(DTA, beside=T, col=c("blue","maroon"), names.arg=1:4,
  ylab="Nr of Cells", xlab="Nuclii", main=lbl)
```

[image]

Now we see that a chi-squared test gives a significant
result. Because the P-value (essentially 0) is much below 5%,
the proportions of various numbers (1 through 4) of nuclii 
are not the same between the two groups.

```
MAT.chisq = chisq.test(MAT);  MAT.chisq

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  MAT
X-squared = 320.32, df = 3, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

The observed counts $X_{ij}, i=1,2,3,4; j = 1,2$ are as follows.

```
MAT.chisq$obs
       a   b
[1,] 101 358
[2,]  79 115
[3,] 159  69
[4,] 203  27
```

Under the null hypothesis that proportions for various numbers of nuclii are
the same for the two groups, the expected counts $E_{ij}$ are as follows:

```
 MAT.chisq$exp
             a         b
[1,] 223.92259 235.07741
[2,]  94.64266  99.35734
[3,] 111.22952 116.77048
[4,] 112.20522 117.79478
```

Then the chi-squared statistic, `X-squared` in the output, is

$$Q = \sum_{i,j} \frac{(X_{ij}-E_{ij})^2}{E_{ij}} = 320.32.$$

The quantities $R_{ij} = (X_{ij} - E_{ij})/\sqrt{E_{ij}}$ from which
$Q$ is computed are called 'Pearson residuals'. Notice that 
$Q = \sum_{i,j} R_{ij}^2.$ When the null hypothesis is rejected, as here,
one looks at the residuals to see which of them is large enough
in absolute value to have contributed to $Q$ in a meaningful way.
Residuals with $|R_{ij}| > 2$ are often worth noticing. Here we
have very large residuals in the first and last rows.

```
MAT.chisq$resi
             a         b
[1,] -8.214531  8.017265
[2,] -1.607930  1.569317
[3,]  4.529492 -4.420720
[4,]  8.571451 -8.365615
```

For example, under the null hypothesis, we would have 'expected' $X_{11} = 101$ to have
been about $E_{11} \approx 224.$ So there are many fewer cells in the first
group with 1 nucleus than would have been expected.

**Comparing two proportions.** You asked specifically about the last row, where observed counts were
$203$ and  $27$ contrasted with expected counts about $112$ and $118.$

It is possible to test just the data for 4 nuclii making a comparison
of the two proportions $0.472$ in the first group and $0.4745$ in the second.

This test can also be done in R, but I show results from Minitab
software below, where the P-value printed as `0.000` means the the P-value
is smaller than $0.0005.$ (Minitab prints these P-values to three places only.)

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample    X    N  Sample p
1       303  642  0.471963
2        27  569  0.047452

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  0.424511
95% CI for difference:  (0.382128, 0.466894)
Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  
    Z = 16.56  P-Value = 0.000
```

As mentioned above, this test can also be done in R, we use `$`-notation below to show only the P-value:

```
prop.test(c(303,27), c(642,569))$p.val
[1] 4.015032e-61
```

Looking at various differences in a larger table, one has to be wary of
'false discovery'. Here the Bonferroni method of avoiding false discovery
says we should look for P-values below about 1%. With such a very small
P-value for this particular difference it seems safe to say that it is 
significant.

*Note:* One could use numbers of nuclii in each group as numerical
data and do a t.test on the two groups, obtaining a highly significant result (shown below). Even though the data (taking only small integer values) are
clearly not normal, the t test may technically give a correct result.

For me however, a major objection to using the t test is that it obscures the
distribution of nuclii in the two groups and the details of the differences between the groups.

```
x.0 = rep(1:4, a); x.100 = rep(1:4, b)
table(x.0)
x.0
  1   2   3   4 
101  79 159 203 
table(x.100)
x.100
  1   2   3   4 
358 115  69  27 

t.test(x.0, x.100)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x.0 and x.100
t = 20.988, df = 1026.7, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means 
   is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.150440 1.387748
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 2.856089  1.586995
```