# Chi-squared - How to deal with replications ; proportion or numbers?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, biostatistics

I am studying the effect of different treatments on the number of male, female and hermaphrodite flowers per plant (M, F , H). For each plant studied, I have these 3 numbers.( ex : 250, 11 and 10). I think it's better to run a Chi-squared  test to see if the proportion of female, male and hermaphrodite flowers is different according to the treatment. However, I have 3 plants per treatment (3 replications).

- How could I deal with the different replications to run the Chi-squared ? Should I take the average of my 4 plants in order to get an average number of each type of flowers and then run the khi 2 with the average numbers?
- For some plants, the number of male flowers is 0, would it be a problem to run the Chi-squared  with a 0 value ?
- Should I use the proportions ( 10% of M, 40% of H and 50% of F for example ), or should I use the real numbers?

I was thinking to do a table with each treatment in column, and M, F and H in lines.

Comment: Duplicated with https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/420015/comparison-of-multiple-frequencies-which-test-should-i-use

Comment: Yes but these are other questions

Comment: For chi-squared tests, use counts, not proportions or averages.